# Pug mixin and layout extends in one file

Tags: node.js, pug

Currently I have a layout.pug that contains the basic layout like containers etc from bootstrap.
this layout is `extends layout.pug` on every page I have.

Now I wanted to try to build a mixin and wanted to `extends` it too but how can I extends multiple files?

My view:

```
extends layout.pug
extends form-mixin.pug

block content
    form(method='post' action="/Autherize")
        div(style='margin: auto; width: 22%; margin-top: 200px;')
            h1 Login
            +NewFormField('username', 'Benutzername')
            +NewFormField('password', 'Passwort')
            button.btn.btn-primary(value='login', type='sumbit') Submit
```

form-mixin:

```
mixin NewFormField(attribute, name)
    .form-group
        label(for='#{attribute}') #{name}
        input.form-control(type='text', placeholder='#{name}', name='#{attribute}')
```

Answer (score 2):

Mixins doesn't get `extends` but `include`.

The view should start like this:

```
extends layout.pug
include form-mixin.pug
```